# Why can I access a WSDL file from a browser, but not from application?

Tags: .net, web-services, vb6, asmx

We've having trouble deploying a web service that works in our development environment, but not in production.  Part of the problem is that our production servers are load-balanced, so to upgrade one of the servers, we have to take it out of the load-balance and try to test the sever in isolation, which is a challenge.

The computer I'm working on is called `Web01` and the computer I'm using to test is called `Ts01`.  On both machines, I've modified the hosts file to redirect `example.com` to the appropriate IP of the web site on `Web01`.

I'm testing two ways of accessing the web service on each machine:

- A simple browser call to `http://www.example.com/services/myservice.asmx?WSDL`.
- A VB6 test app that calls the web service using the WSDL referenced above via `SOAPClient`.

Here are the results of the test:

```
                   Browser              VB6 App
    Ts01             OK                   OK
    Web01            OK                  ERROR
```

The test seems to work OK for every situation except the VB6 app installed on the web server.  The Error I get back is :

> -2147024809 - WSDLReader:Loading of the WSDL file failed HRESULT=0x80070057 - WSDLReader:XML Parser failed at linenumber 0, lineposition 0, reason is: The system cannot locate the object specified.
>
> HRESULT=0x1

I get the same error back on `Ts01` if I supply a bad WSDL address in the VB6 app.  It seems as if the VB6 application on `Web01` can't access the web service dll on `Web01`, which is a big problem.

It may be worth noting that it works on my local developer machine as well, where I have the VB6 app and the web service installed on the same machine.

Why might the VB6 app be having trouble communicating with the web service via `SOAPClient` when run from the same box that the web service exists?

---

I used fiddler to inspect the headers of the requests on my local machine calling our dev server.  Here's the difference between the browser and SOAPclient requests:

Browser:

```
GET http://devserver/services/myservice.asmx?WSDL HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, application/xaml+xml, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-ms-application, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: devserver
Cookie: SIFR-PREFETCHED=true
```

SOAPClient (from VB6 App):

```
GET http://devserver/services/myservice.asmx?WSDL HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: hbhswebnet
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

I'm not sure if that information is helpful, but perhaps it is.

Comment: Have you considered it may be a permissions error? It's possible VB6 app on Web01 does not have permission to make a SOAPClient call.

Comment: I don't believe this to be a programming problem; it belongs on ServerFault

Comment: Are you accessing the remote machine via a Web proxy?

Comment: @Joel I'm not sure about that, but I'll check into it.

Comment: @0xA3 What does it mean to access via web proxy? I log in to both machines via remote desktop (mstsc.exe). Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Josh: I believe he needs to change his program to deal with the apparent networking difference, rather than correcting the network infrastructure.

Comment: @Ben: can you run the VB6 app on your local machine or on TS01, but have it try to access the WSDL on WEB01?

Comment: @John That's a great idea. Unfortunately we don't have fiddler installed on any of those machines and I can't access them from my local machine because they're in a different secure domain.  I'll probably check with our LAN team to follow up on some of these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general pattern:

> Q:  "**x**" works in the browser, but fails in a program that's doing the same thing the browser is doing. What's wrong?
>
> A: the program is *not* doing the same thing the browser is doing.

Browsers explicitly set headers that your program is not setting (especially since you're using the very obsolete SOAPClient). Various pieces of networking equipment and software may look at these headers in deciding how to respond to your requests.

You should look at the network traffic for both cases (browser and program) using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or something, then look carefully for differences between the way the browser behaves and the way your program behaves. You may then either change the program to be like the browser, or ask your networking people to please reduce security so that your program can access the service.

Comment: that's great advice, esp. the idea of using Fiddler.  I hadn't thought about doing that to examine the request headers.  I guess what surprised me most was that it *does work* on one machine, but not the machine that will actually be responsible for making the call.

Comment: @Ben: based on the headers you posted, I'd ask the networking people about that SIFR-PREFETCHED=true cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look at is the proxy settings in the browser, are you going through a proxy?  VB6 picks up some, but not all of the proxy settings from Internet Explorer, but none from any other browser.

If Fiddler doesn't work, you may have to roll up your sleaves and dig into [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), to find out why VB6 isn't communicating.

Another important thing to look at is, is what SOAP Client are you using?   (Microsofts antiquated and buggy client, PocketSOAP, something home brewed?)  One suggestion might be to write a soap proxy for .Net and then use interop to work with your soap.

Answer (score 0):

"WSDLReader error '80020009' 
WSDLReader:XML Parser failed at linenumber 0, lineposition 0, reason is: The server name or address could not be resolved HRESULT=0x1: Incorrect function. - WSDLReader:Loading of the WSDL file failed HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect. - Client:One of the parameters supplied is invalid. HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect. "

Windows Update corrupted registry and web application will not initiate any object related your web service and will you get this error.
Try to Re-Register you SOAP Clients and SOAP Dlls or try reinstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the WSDL files and/or service itself requires authentication. In my case (assuming Basic Auth) I had to provide credentials to the SOAP connection URL, so:

```
http://www.example.com/services/myservice.asmx?WSDL
```

becomes:

```
http://user:password@www.example.com/services/myservice.asmx?WSDL
```

Of course, this is totally insecure on the public Internet, so you should use HTTPS. You should also limit connections only to trusted hosts if possible.

This may or may not work with certain security updates to your browser or with MSXML:

https://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;832414

In which case you may have to provide the credentials using other methods. If you can get the WSDL file accessible without credentials, you can still secure the service with credentials and pass them in the SOAP envelope:

```
  sc.ssoapinit(WSDLURL)
  sc.ConnectorProperty("AuthUser") = "user"
  sc.ConnectorProperty("AuthPassword") = "password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Code would work on my machine but not the clients. Had to load IE-Tools-Internet Options and click on Advanced. Scroll down to Security and unchecked "Do not save encrypted pages to disk".